# Nodejs error has no traceback

Tags: node.js

I'm somewhat new to nodejs.

Using express / npm.

Once i hit '/' from my browser, I get this in output:

```
[TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'push']
```

No line numbers, no traceback, nothing.

I need to be able to fix this error, and to do that I need to know what file / line # this occurred.

How do I get nodejs to output a traceback?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, add an express error handler, which is middleware expecting 4 arguments:

```
app.use(function (error, req, res, next) {
  console.error(error.stack);
});
```

Make sure to put the above code **at the very end of your middleware stack** after all your normal middleware and route handlers are defined.

If that doesn't get you your stack trace, catch process-level uncaught exceptions:

```
process.on("uncaughtException", function (error) {
  console.error(error.stack);
});
```

And one final tip would be run your app under the debugger with `node --debug=3001 app.js`, connect to it with node-inspector, open the debugger in chrome, enable "stop on exceptions", then trigger the error. The debugger will take you to the line where the exception occurs.

Comment: Hmm this did not work for me.  I think the issue is that it is not getting to the point where the error method is called.

What is happening is, when I make a request, it calls routes/index.js.  Somewhere there is a type error, and therefore it never gets to response.send the output.  So the browser hangs (no response / timeout), and nodejs never does a traceback.

Maybe I am using the wrong structure here.

Comment: Express will catch exceptions that happen in the same tick as the router dispatch methods, but not async exceptions in different stacks. Those WILL get caught by node's top-level process object. If you've correctly set up both things as I describe, you WILL catch the error. But at this point it's up to you to post a minimal code snippet as per the stack overflow guidelines.

Comment: Thanks Peter.  After further scrutinizing I found I was calling console.error(error) in the process event handler.  This was from code I found on another stackoverflow answer.  After changing it to error.stack, everything is now dandy.  Thanks again.